# Pandas - Filter DataFrame with Logics

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this,

```
Employee ID     ActionCode     ActionReason      ConcatenatedOutput
1                  TER              DEA                TER_DEA                
1                  RET              ABC                RET_ABC
1                  RET              DEF                RET_DEF
2                  TER              DEA                TER_DEA
2                  ABC              ABC                ABC_ABC
2                  DEF              DEF                DEF_DEF
3                  RET              FGH                RET_FGH
3                  RET              EFG                RET_EFG
4                  PLA              ABC                PLA_ABC
4                  TER              DEA                TER_DEA
```

And I want to filter it with the below logics and change it to something like this,

```
Employee ID          ConcatenatedOutput       Context
1                     RET_ABC                 RET or TER Found
2                     TER_DEA                 RET or TER Found
3                     RET_FGH                 RET or TER Found
4                     PLA_ABC                 RET or TER Not Found
```

Logics:-
1) If the first record of an Employee is TER_DEA then we go in to that employee and see if that employee has any other records, If that employee has another RET record, then we pick up the first available RET record or else we stick to TER_DEA record.

2)  if the first record of an employee is anything other than TER_DEA then we stick with that record.

3) Context is conditional if it has a RET or TER then we say RET or TER Found, else it is not found.

***Note:- The final output will have only one record for an employee ID.***

The data below,

```
employee_id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
action_code = ['TER','RET','RET','TER','ABC','DEF','RET','RET','PLA','TER']
action_reason = ['DEA','ABC','DEF','DEA','ABC','DEF','FGH','EFG','ABC','DEA']
concatenated_output = ['TER_DEA', 'RET_ABC', 'RET_DEF', 'TER_DEA', 'ABC_ABC', 'DEF_DEF', 'RET_FGH', 'RET_EFG', 'PLA_ABC', 'TER_DEA']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Employee ID': employee_id,
    'ActionCode': action_code,
    'ActionReason': action_reason,
    'ConcatenatedOutput': concatenated_output,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you rather go with a Bool in that field. To get the test data I used this:

```
import pandas as pd

employee_id = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
action_code = ['TER','RET','RET','TER','ABC','DEF','RET','RET','PLA','TER']
action_reason = ['DEA','ABC','DEF','DEA','ABC','DEF','FGH','EFG','ABC','DEA']
concatenated_output = ['TER_DEA', 'RET_ABC', 'RET_DEF', 'TER_DEA', 'ABC_ABC', 'DEF_DEF', 'RET_FGH', 'RET_EFG', 'PLA_ABC', 'TER_DEA']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Employee ID': employee_id,
    'ActionCode': action_code,
    'ActionReason': action_reason,
    'ConcatenatedOutput': concatenated_output,
})
```

You can then do a group by on the employee ID and and apply a function to perform your specific program logic in there.

```
def myfunc(data):
    if data.iloc[0]['ConcatenatedOutput'] == 'TER_DEA':
        if len(data.loc[data['ActionCode'] == 'RET']) > 0:
            located_record = data.loc[data['ActionCode'] == 'RET'].iloc[[0]]
        else:
            located_record = data.iloc[[0]]
    else:
        located_record = data.iloc[[0]]
    located_record['RET or TER Context'] = data['ActionCode'].str.contains('|'.join(['RET', 'TER']))
    return located_record

df.groupby(['Employee ID']).apply(myfunc)
```

Comment: Again, the problem here is not the conditional column but eliminating the duplicate records based on the logics

Comment: Thanks. But can you help me with the function. I am not sure, how can I change the function to look for TER_DEA and then look for the next RET record.

Comment: Busy with it, 1 sec.

Comment: Checking. Give me 10 minutes please.

Comment: Remember to accept and like if it solved your question.